# Automapper Convert in dictionary class value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I want to make a web response object from a service layer object.
For the service layer object I have:

```
public class clothdata
{
    public clothname {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, int> textilenode {get;set;}
}
```

Which I want to convert to

```
public class clothdataview
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public clothname {get;set;}
    [JsonPropertyName("textile summary")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> textilenode {get;set;}
}
```

The mapper is just converting the type of value in textilenode from integer to string (I will/may convert to other types in the future).

For controller I have written the mapper:

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<clothdata, clothdataview>()
```

But I don't know how to write the `.formember` part

Can you advise ?

Thank you

Comment: You miss the `clothname` type I suppose `string` anyway you can read the  [Automapper Docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/) but you don't need the mapper for the Dictionary is automatic.

Comment: `ForMember` is not needed if the names of the properties are same and is able to cast

Answer (score 1):

So, what is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using AutoMapper;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<clothdata, clothdataview>(); });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var source = new clothdata { clothname = "First", textilenode = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Foo", 1 } } };
            var dest = mapper.Map<clothdataview>(source);

            var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(dest);
            // Output: {"name":"First","textile summary":{"Foo":"1"}}
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
    }

    public class clothdata
    {
        public string clothname { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> textilenode { get; set; }
    }

    public class clothdataview
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string clothname { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("textile summary")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> textilenode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LcBHGi